# converting session statement?

Tags: php, session

i've just started learning php, i'm using an if statement to control what will be displayed on my webpage depending on whether a user is logged in or not.

I know how to show things to the user if they are logged in under their session, by using this session statement. But how would i create the reverse to tell the site to display something else if the user is not logged in under their session?

Here's the code i'm using.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
    if ($user['id'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
        if ($user['account_type'] == "platinum"){ ?>
            <html stuff>
        <?}
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Where did you learn programming if you don't know about `else` clauses? PHP's `if` statements are similar to those of almost every other language.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are new to programming, not just PHP. Welcome to the community!

You are looking for the [`else`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) part of the `if`-statement. This is common to many programming languages.

Here is an example to get you started.

```
<?php 

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) 
{ 
    if ($user['id'] == $_SESSION['user_id'])
    {
        if ($user['account_type'] == "platinum")
        { 
            print "Welcome, platinum user";
        }
        else
        {
            print "Welcome, non-platinum user";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print "Unexpected session";
    }
}
else
{
    print "You are not logged in";
}

?>
```